# repair air intake and exhaust and gas lines on a 2013 china yy50cc qt-6 scooter

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, scooter

I am having difficulty identifying where my vacuum and fuel lines terminate on the carburetor and various other components of this vehicle after disassembly.

Can someone assist me with a visual aid in order for me to properly reassemble my vehicle?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

So you stripped everything down and now don't know how to get them back..?
Okay, once you fit your carb on the engine, you'll have a angled rubber tube (manifold) between a cylinder head and carburetor. On the side of that manifold should be a little fitting for a hose pipe. That hose pipe is sending a vacuum from manifold to a fuel pump that is located under the fuel tank. There are 2 options - mounted to a fuel tank (pic 1), or fitted on a frame, away from a fuel tank (pic 2).
[image]

[image]

Right fitting (pic 1) or green hose (pic 2) is where goes the other end of that hose pipe. It's a circular membrane inside of a pump, that is being pulled by vacuum, and pushed back by spring, and pumps the fuel.

---

At the pic 1 another fitting is a fuel pipe fitting for sending a fuel to a carburetor, so plug a pine on it, and other end of a pipe on a carburetor. I'm Googling your carb now, and can't find the way how to explain which fitting on carb is for fuel intake, and which is for overflow. So if you're struggling with it, post a picture, we will figure it out.